# Uso do this em Java

Tags: java

Olá, no código abaixo, eu apenas coloquei o this no atributo tamanho porque tem um parâmetro com o mesmo nome que ele, para que o compilador não se confunda. Mas estou na dúvida se coloco nos outros também.

```
public class Pilha {
    private int tamanho;
    private Object[] vetor;
    private int topo;

public Pilha(int tamanho) {
    this.tamanho = tamanho;
    vetor = new Object[this.tamanho];
    topo = -1;
}
```

Eu sempre vejo meus professores referenciando todos os atributos da classe, em todos os métodos, com o this, independente se houver ou não uma variável local com mesmo nome que possa fazer o compilador entender errado. Se não há esse tipo de variável, o compilador já não entende que esses atributos são referentes aos da classe sem o uso do this?

Eu quero entender principalmente como funciona o compilador na hora de ler esse código.
Se pra ele fica melhor usar o this mesmo sem nada que possa o confundir ou não.

Caso vocês tenham algum material bom sobre esse tipo de assunto, estou aceitando indicações.